# FacebookGraphAPIのレート制限に伴う影響範囲について

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Meta for DevelopersよりFacebookアプリを作成し、
「Facebookログイン機能」と「Facebookページへの記事投稿処理」を実装しています。
APIのレート制限で一方がスロットリングされた場合、もう一方の機能にもスロットリングがなされるのでしょうか？

公式ドキュメントにて、各アクセストークン毎にレート制限が設けられているのは認識してます。
しかし、レート制限とアクセストークンとの関連性まで言及されていないように見うけられます。
ご存じの方いればご教示頂ければ幸いです。

■前提
「Facebookログイン機能」ではユーザアクセストークンを利用。
「Facebookページへの記事投稿処理」ではページアクセストークンを利用。
各アクセストークン毎にレート制限が設けられている認識。

■公式ドキュメント
・APIレート制限
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting